# Sending a value of BTC0.00

Tags: transactions

I'm monitoring [The Shadow Brokers](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/08/17/cisco_two_shadow_brokers_vulnerabilities_real/) wallet out of curiosity on how big it will become, and I've noticed that a transaction with a value of £0.00 was sent. How can this be?

The transaction I'm referencing is: [da849be1571092b467da9be31bcb0a43508bde5776173954bdba0d48845bd842](https://blockchain.info/tx/da849be1571092b467da9be31bcb0a43508bde5776173954bdba0d48845bd842)

[image]

It was my assumed understanding that you can't send a value of nothing (in this case £0.00) as when I try and send BTC0.00/£0.00, [my client](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/blockchain-bitcoin-wallet/id493253309?mt=8) always asks me to input a value.

Utlimately, my question is **how** and **why** would someone send £0.00.

<sup>The why may be impacted by the urge to contribute to the wallet funds for NSA 0days.</sup>

Comment: related: [Are transactions containing zero-value output accepted by miners?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/30370/5406)

Comment: It is not 0 , the value of output is 0.00001 BTC . Change currency from pound to BTC

Comment: @darkknight My mistake! That didn't even occur to me to change the output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How would someone send £0.00?

The [transaction](https://blockchain.info/tx/da849be1571092b467da9be31bcb0a43508bde5776173954bdba0d48845bd842) you mentioned sent .00001 BTC to
`19BY2XCgbDe6WtTVbTyzM9eR3LYr6VitWK` which is the [Shadow Brokers](http://www.npr.org/sections/thetwo-way/2016/08/17/490329015/shadow-brokers-claim-to-have-hacked-the-nsas-hackers) account. £0.00 is only a rounded number when converting to fiat. Disregarding this transaction, it is possible to send Bitcoin transactions with [no BTC value](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/30370/are-transactions-containing-zero-value-output-accepted-by-miners)

> why would someone send £0.00?

Your why question is more speculative, but sending dust is a common (low cost) tactic for [chain analysis companies](https://www.chainalysis.com/) to tie bitcoin addresses together in the future. In this case it is likely that many chain analysis companies (on their own or on behalf of government clients) will attempt to identify the owners of that Bitcoin account.